# Iframe on Blogger javascript not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, blogger

I have iframe that cointains some javascript that should fire on body load,while iframe works fine when embedded on plain HTML page,when integrated in blogger HTML/javascript widget,javascript in iframe don't work..suggestions.Tried only in Firefox bc viruses and toolbars eaten IE?

Iframe Page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title> 
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function change() {
           var text = "someaddress";
           window.location = "http://something.com/fb2.aspx" + "?url=" + text;
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#333333" onload="change()">
</body>
</html>
```

Code of HTML/javascript widget on Blogger Blog

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://something.com/fb.htm" width="200" height="70" 
frameborder="0" name="myInlineFrame"></iframe>
```

And sam iframe embedded in this plain HTML page executes javascript as it should

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Stats page</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="fb.htm" runat="server" id="iframe1" width="500" height="500"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps a link to where this was deployed would help?  What is it that this code is supposed to do?

Comment: Pass var text to fb2.aspx as url parametar by redirecting to it..

Comment: Code seems correct,really no place to miss but i was wondering maybe somebody else expreinced problem executing java in blogger iframe..because code is trivial

Comment: I got that part, are you trying to redirect the top level page to that or just the iframe?  Why not just hard-code "someaddress" into the iframe src?  A better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish would help us find you an answer :)

Comment: Executing Java???? Or do you mean JavaScript???

Comment: just iframe,problem is any javascript won't work in this iframe when integrated as widget on blogger this is just one of things I've tried

Comment: Javascript*...you know what I mean

Comment: I tried adding input Text1 and then 
function change() {
    var text = "someadress";
    document.getElementById('Text1').value = text;


}
Once agian works when iframe on html page..on blogger..nothing!

Comment: Hmm, it's not same origin, I just tried on my web server...  It might be the widget technology invalidating your JavaScript.  Depending on how the widgets are injected, that could have an affect.  How does your browser source look?

Comment: You should try adding your iframe directly to the template itself, instead of as a widget.  That would tell us if the widget functionality is importing your JS in a manner that precludes execution.

Comment: Hardcode..yep..can't do this bc is just snippent if I can't get even this to work how would I get var text = parent.document.URL; to work...

Comment: this is part of source from blogger looks like widgets are hardcoded 
<div class='sidebar section' id='sidebar-right-1'><div class='widget HTML' id='HTML1'>
<h2 class='title'>widget</h2>
<div class='widget-content'>
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://something.com/fb.htm" width="200" height="70" 
frameborder="0" name="myInlineFrame">
</iframe>
</div>
I have read somewhere that Blogger have trouble with double quotes but it displays Iframe correctly only javascript don't get executed

Comment: Hmmm, check to make sure you have http : // in the src attribute, like src="http://comething.com/fb.htm".  If that's not the problem, check my answer below as I verified it works on my own Blog.

Comment: Sorry, my comment, and prob yours too, got cannibilised.  I was trying to say to make sure src="h t t p : / /" was present before your domain in the iframe src.  The comment system cuts it off in the actual links, but I really think the problem is simply the widgets system ...

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, it appears that the Blogger Widget/Gadget system is using a method of adding code to the DOM that precludes the execution of any JavaScript.  Oftentimes, this can happen if content is added by appending it to the .innerHTML object.  The DOM element is rendered, but any included JavaScript does not execute.

A workaround for this is outside the scope of this question, because it's a blogger issue.

The solution for you is to edit the Blogger template directly, and paste your IFRAME where you would like it to appear in the template itself.  In other words, don't use a widget.

Below is a portion of my own Blogger Template with an iframe right before the closing body element:

```
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
  window.setTimeout(function() {
     document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(&#39;loading&#39;, &#39;&#39;);
   }, 10);
  </script>

  <!-- Iframe in template -->
  <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://somedomain.com/fb.htm" width="200" height="70" 
     frameborder="0" name="myInlineFrame"></iframe>
  <!-- Iframe in template -->

</body>

  <macro:includable id='sections' var='col'>
   <macro:if cond='data:col.num == 0'>
   <macro:else/>
```

Comment: This is getting really wierd..hardcoded it to template..and still nothing..Are you using Firefox?